# Frequent subgraph mining with igraph

Tags: python, r, graph, data-mining, igraph

Is there a function in igraph that allows discovering all frequent subgraphs in a given graph? Something along the lines of [gSpan](https://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~xyan/software/gSpan.htm) for instance.

Answer (score 1):

R has got a package [`subgraphMining`](http://www.csc.ncsu.edu/faculty/samatova/practical-graph-mining-with-R/PracticalGraphMiningWithR.html), which - among other things - has implemented `gSpan`. However, it depends on the outdated [`igraph0`](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/igraph0/) package.

From the help `?gspan` it would look like this:

```
library(subgraphMining)
library(igraph0)
graph1 = graph.ring(5)
graph2 = graph.ring(6)

database = array(dim=2);
database[1] = list(graph1);
database[2] = list(graph2);

# Call gspan, 80% frequency
results = gspan(database, "80%");
results
#  [[1]]
# Vertices: 5
# Edges: 10
# Directed: TRUE
# Edges:
# 
# [0] '1' -> '5'
# [1] '5' -> '1'
# [2] '2' -> '1'
# [3] '1' -> '2'
# [4] '3' -> '2'
# [5] '2' -> '3'
# [6] '4' -> '3'
# [7] '3' -> '4'
# [8] '5' -> '4'
# [9] '4' -> '5'
```